# Button click - progress animation

Tags: android, button, android-animation

How can I get animation effect similar to following on button click ?

[image]

I don't need to control the progress, I just need it filled in a second after button click. 
I also don't need the text color changing.

I am at loss as to where to start for this kind of animation. Any help to put me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: This could be a layer-list drawable with an animation for just the layer with the "filled" rectangle shape. Alternatively, one could look into path animations like [here](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html#clipping-paths)

Answer (score 5):

At first, create a frame layout, like following

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_style" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="18dp"
        android:text="Downloading"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Then create a file `progress_bar_style.xml` put it into your drawable folder

The content of the `progress_bar_style.xml` will be following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:centerColor="#FFFEFE"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>



    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#3F51B5"
                    android:centerColor="#3F51B5"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#3F51B5"
                    android:angle="270"
                    />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Here is how you will implement in activity /fragment

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        final ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress",
                progressBar.getProgress(), 100).setDuration(2000);

        objectAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                int progress = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        });

        TextView btn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                objectAnimator.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I already have a button background. Throwing the progressbar either over or under does not work. Under hides the progress bar. Over even with transparency does not look good.